# How to produce SVG that would fill the entire screen?

Tags: r, r-grid

The code below creates a circle using the R grid graphics. I would expect the chart to fill the entire screen instead it fills only a fraction (top-left) of the screen. I am on a Windows computer and here is what the produced svg looks like when I open it using Chrome. How can I draw a circle that would fill the entire screen? I am looking to understand how things work so would appreciate someone teaching me the part I am missing here or pointing me to a reference that I can learn from.

[image: (top]

```
library("grid")
library("gridSVG")
grid.newpage()
grid.circle()
grid.export("rectangle.svg")
```

Comment: Seems likely that you are using the defaults for the graphics device. Try making the graphics device bigger.

Comment: Strange, but I have a normal output with your code.

Comment: @manro: note that the R graphics device is normal (circle fills the whole device) but the saved svg one ("rectangle.svg") is not for me (circle fills only top left part).

Comment: @ColorStatistics Yes, now I see your problem.

Comment: @IRTFM: Thank you for the pointer. I am reading on that now and will return if I still can't figure it out.